# Mapbox Studio - Changing appearance of live map

Tags: mapbox

I've been using MapBox studio for a few weeks now but I'm curious, using the API is it possible to change the look of a map using html UI elements? For example, if I want to have a slider on the page which is displaying my map which adjusts the size of the POI labels, is it possible to do that, or am I beholden to the current saved .mss file for those attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Mapbox Studio is designed for the rendering of raster tiles and not for live-changing styles. Check out [Mapbox GL](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-gl) for preview of how live styling will work.